# Nginx error in MacOS?

Tags: macos, nginx

I am getting the below error while working with `Nginx` with MacOS.

> nginx: [emerg] invalid socket number "/usr/local/nginx/sbin" in NGINX
>   environment variable, ignoring

Answer (score 1):

You should unset the `NGINX` environment variable before starting nginx. This probably means running `unset NGINX` in the shell / in your startup script before running nginx.

The `NGINX` environment variable is used internally by nginx and should not be set. For details see https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/900